# Windows cannot load extensible counter

Tags: windows

I got this error for 100,000 times

Windows cannot load extensible counter DLL .NET Data Provider for Oracle, the first DWORD in data section is the Windows error code.

What can you sugget to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

I would run through the procedure referenced in the article below to rebuild the performance counters on the problem machine. I haven't seen exactly the symptom you're reporting, but I have found that this procedure helps with general performance counter strangeness in most cases.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300956